# Paste graphic in original size

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

If I paste a graphic into PowerPoint it gets automatically enlarged, however I just want the graphic in it's original size. How can I do that? Thank you very much! I am on PowerPoint 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out, PowerPoint already pastes the graphic in it's original size, however zooming was enabled by default (check the lower right corner of powerpoint, set it to 100% if it isn't already at 100%), so not the picture was resized but the whole slide. I didn't notice that. @panickal: Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3):

After inserting the picture, try `Reset Picture & Size` in the `Format` tab under `Picture Tools`. Or for the longer method, right-click on the picture and use the `Scale` option in `Size and Position` to set the height and width to 100%.